# SQL Date Formatting from String

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am stuck trying to convert the following strings formatted like this `26-09-2021-02-54-03` (DD-MM-YYYY-hh-mm-ss) into timestamp or in this format YYYY-MM-DD HH:DD:SS in BigQuery. Any idea how to process?

I cannot use `PARSE_TIMESTAMP()` since there is no T in the string.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to parse it with the following:

```
select '26-09-2021-02-54-03'
    , PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S", '26-09-2021-02-54-03')
    , FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F %X",PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S", '26-09-2021-02-54-03'))
```

For more information on the format elements see:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#supported_format_elements_for_timestamp